# Count first occurrence of duplicate in Access

Tags: excel-formula, ms-access-2007

I would like to count the unique properties by market.

In the dataset below, I would like it to return a count of 1 for Seattle, 2 for North California, and 1 for Louisiana.

| Market Area | PropertyID |
| --- | --- |
| Seattle | 123 |
| North Cali | 456 |
| Louisiana | 115 |
| North Cali | 456 |
| North Cali | 789 |

I've done this in Excel, but there is too much data now where it starts crashing. I put in a count if formula where it compares the current cell with all the cells above it. If the same propertyId appears above it, it assigns it a zero. If its a new propertyID, it gets a 1. I then use a pivot table to get the counts by market area. =IF(COUNTIF($A$2:A530149,A530149)>1,0,1)

I tried using this SQL code, but it doesn't match with what I have in Excel.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Count(PropertyID) AS UniqueHomes, MarketArea
FROM AR
WHERE (((AR.invdate)>=#3/1/2022# And (AR.invdate)<=#2/28/2023#))
GROUP BY MarketArea;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do:

```sql
SELECT MarketArea, Count(*) AS UniqueHomes
FROM AR
WHERE (((AR.invdate)>=#3/1/2022# And (AR.invdate)<=#2/28/2023#))
GROUP BY MarketArea;
```

Comment: Did it work for you?